# Foreign Key in different schema SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created a foreign key from one table cnfg.Account to another table dict.Types, the schema are different, no problem with that, after creating the FK, I can browse the table in the Management Studio, go to Keys and my new FK is there, but if right click the table and I click 
Design and after that right click to see the Relationships... my new FK is not there.
it is because the schema are different?
Thank you.

Comment: No, it is probably because the visual designers in Management Studio SUCK.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find a specific bug about this on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/sql) but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist or that Microsoft isn't aware of it. However, since you are quite unlikely to see a fix for this back-ported to older versions (most remaining bugs have been closed as won't fix over the past year or two), I highly recommend moving to the SQL Server 2012 version of Management Studio. I've validated that this issue doesn't occur there ([click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZTfS.png)):

[image]

(Those tables are `x.a` and `y.b`, the UI just has a funny way of showing that.)

You will still be able to manage all of your SQL Server 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2. And if you don't have a license already, that's ok! You don't need one anymore as of [SQL Server 2012 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579).

Stop using old tools they won't fix. And/or learn the DDL instead of relying on the visual designers. They get slightly better with each release but they're not a crutch you want to rely on.